# Send http request through specific network interface

Tags: python, python-requests

I have two network interfaces (wifi and ethernet) both with internet access. Let's say my interfaces are `eth` (ethernet) and `wlp2` (wifi). I need specific requests to go through `eth` interface and others through `wpl2`.

Something like:

```
// Through "eth"
request.post(url="http://myapi.com/store_ip", iface="eth")
// Through "wlp2" 
request.post(url="http://myapi.com/log", iface="wlp2")
```

I'm using `requests`, but I can use `pycurl` or `urllib` if there isn't any way to do it with `requests`.

[How to specify source interface in python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335544/how-to-specify-source-interface-in-python-requests-module) refers to [Requests, bind to an ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip) and it doesn't work.

Comment: I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055104/monkey-patching-sockets-library-to-use-a-specifc-network-interface/53057280#53057280) which has two answers now. There is a simple one that does not meet all of my needs, and there is my own answer that I have found and can achieve everything I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way using `pycurl`. This works like a charm.

```
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO
import json


def curl_post(url, data, iface=None):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    buffer = BytesIO()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POST, True)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json'])
    c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 10)
    c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
    if iface:
        c.setopt(pycurl.INTERFACE, iface)
    c.perform()

    # Json response
    resp = buffer.getvalue().decode('UTF-8')

    #  Check response is a JSON if not there was an error
    try:
        resp = json.loads(resp)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        pass

    buffer.close()
    c.close()
    return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dat = {"id": 52, "configuration": [{"eno1": {"address": "192.168.1.1"}}]}
    res = curl_post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/network_configuration/", json.dumps(dat), "wlp2")
    print(res)
```

I'm leaving the question opened hopping that someone can give an answer using `requests`.

Comment: Why curl Windows does not supprt specific "--interface"?

Answer (score 17):

Here is the solution for Requests library without monkey-patching anything.

This function will create a Session bound to the given IP address. It is up to you to determine IP address of the desired network interface.

Tested to work with `requests==2.23.0`.

```
import requests


def session_for_src_addr(addr: str) -> requests.Session:
    """
    Create `Session` which will bind to the specified local address
    rather than auto-selecting it.
    """
    session = requests.Session()
    for prefix in ('http://', 'https://'):
        session.get_adapter(prefix).init_poolmanager(
            # those are default values from HTTPAdapter's constructor
            connections=requests.adapters.DEFAULT_POOLSIZE,
            maxsize=requests.adapters.DEFAULT_POOLSIZE,
            # This should be a tuple of (address, port). Port 0 means auto-selection.
            source_address=(addr, 0),
        )

    return session


# usage example:
s = session_for_src_addr('192.168.1.12')
s.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
```

Be warned though that this approach is identical to `curl`'s `--interface` option, and won't help in some cases. Depending on your routing configuration, it might happen that even though you bind to the specific IP address, request will go through some other interface. So if this answer does not work for you then first check if `curl http://httpbin.org/ip --interface myinterface` will work as expected.

Comment: This solved my problem using `requests` with an interface that had two IP addresses in Linux (as `eth0` and `eth0:1`).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this on Linux you could use `SO_BINDTODEVICE` flag for `setsockopt` (check [man 7 socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html#:%7E:text=since%20Linux%204.6.-,SO_BINDTODEVICE,-Bind%20this%20socket), for more details). In fact, it's what used [by curl](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/3df8d08d00a82f0bfc076ca1000abb209e0b9770/lib/connect.c#L305), if you use `--interface` [option](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--interface) on linux. But keep in mind that `SO_BINDTODEVICE` requires root permissions (`CAP_NET_RAW`, although there were [some attempts](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/20200331132009.1306283-1-vincent@bernat.ch/) to change this) and `curl` fallbacks to a regular `bind` trick if `SO_BINDTODEVICE` fails.

Here's sample `curl` strace when it fails:

```
strace -f -e setsockopt,bind curl --interface eth2 https://ifconfig.me/
strace: Process 18208 attached
[pid 18208] +++ exited with 0 +++
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, [60], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, [60], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth2\0", 5) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.8.1")}, 16) = 0 # curl fallbacks to regular bind
127.0.0.1+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Also, wanted to say that using regular `bind` does not always guarantee that traffic would go through specified interface ([@MarSoft answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61581069/4042398) uses plain `bind`). On linux, only `SO_BINDTODEVICE` guarantees that traffic would go through the specified device.

Here's an example how to use `SO_BINDTODEVICE` with `requests` and [requests-toolbelt](https://pypi.org/project/requests-toolbelt/) (as I said, it requires `CAP_NET_RAW` [permissions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html#:%7E:text=listen%20to%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20multicasts.-,CAP_NET_RAW,-*%20Use%20RAW%20and)).

```py
import socket
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters.socket_options import SocketOptionsAdapter


session = requests.Session()
# set interface here
options = [(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, b"eth0")]
for prefix in ('http://', 'https://'):
    session.mount(prefix, SocketOptionsAdapter(socket_options=options))


print(session.get("https://ifconfig.me/").text)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `requests-toolbelt` you can implement adapter class yourself:

```py
import socket
import requests
from requests import adapters
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager


class InterfaceAdapter(adapters.HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.iface = kwargs.pop('iface', None)
        super(InterfaceAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def _socket_options(self):
        if self.iface is None:
            return []
        else:
            return [(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, self.iface)]

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            socket_options=self._socket_options()
        )


session = requests.Session()
for prefix in ('http://', 'https://'):
    session.mount(prefix, InterfaceAdapter(iface=b'eth0'))


print(session.get("https://ifconfig.me/").text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the internal IP (192.168.0.200) to the corresponding iface in the code below.

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import source

def check_ip(inet_addr):
    s = requests.Session()
    iface = source.SourceAddressAdapter(inet_addr)
    s.mount('http://', iface)
    s.mount('https://', iface)
    url = 'https://emapp.cc/get_my_ip'
    resp = s.get(url)
    print(resp.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_ip('192.168.0.200')
```