# Monkey patching sockets library to use a specifc network interface

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to make requests to a website using the `requests` library but using different network interfaces. Following are a list of answers that I have tried to use but did not work.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996494/send-http-request-through-specific-network-interface) describes how to achieve what I want, but it uses `pycurl`. I could use `pycurl` but I have learned about this monkey patching thing and want to give it a try.

This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip/12590625#12590625) seemed to work at first, since it does not raise any error. However, I monitored my network traffic using Wireshark and the packets were sent from my default interface. I tried to print messages inside the function `set_src_addr` defined by the author of the answer but the message did not show up. Therefore, I think it is patching a function that is never called. I get a HTTP 200 response, which should not occur since I have bound my socket to 127.0.0.1.

```
import socket

real_create_conn = socket.create_connection

def set_src_addr(*args):
    address, timeout = args[0], args[1]
    source_address = ('127.0.0.1', 0)
    return real_create_conn(address, timeout, source_address)

socket.create_connection = set_src_addr

import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
r

<Response [200]>
```

I have also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150332/source-interface-with-python-and-urllib2/1150423#1150423). I can get two kind of errors using this method:

```
import socket                  
true_socket = socket.socket    
def bound_socket(*a, **k):     
    sock = true_socket(*a, **k)
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
    return sock                
socket.socket = bound_socket   
import requests
```

This will not allow me to create a socket and raise this [error](https://gist.github.com/alexandredias3d/80a4ab0aea7aaa2db22d7605c325ec7f). I have also tried to make a variation of this answer which looks like this:

```
import requests                           
import socket                             
true_socket = socket.socket               
def bound_socket(*a, **k):                
    sock = true_socket(*a, **k)           
    sock.bind(('192.168.0.10', 0))        
    print(sock)                           
    return sock                           
socket.socket = bound_socket              
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

This also do not work and raises this [error](https://gist.github.com/alexandredias3d/3ae3ae5fe726aeb0b65dcc0865b1b4fe).

I have the following problem: I want to have each process sending requests through a specific network interface. I thought that since threads share global memory (including libraries), I should change my code to work with processes. Now, I want to apply a monkey patching solution somewhere, in a way that each process can use a different interface for communication. Am I missing something? Is this the best way to approach this problem?

**Edit:**
I also would like to know if it is possible for different process to have different versions of the same library. If they are shared, how can I have different versions of a library in Python (one for each process)?

Comment: have you tried using the `unittest.mock` library? It seems fairly necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work for python3:

```
In [1]: import urllib3

In [2]: real_create_conn = urllib3.util.connection.create_connection

In [3]: def set_src_addr(address, timeout, *args, **kw):
   ...:     source_address = ('127.0.0.1', 0)
   ...:     return real_create_conn(address, timeout=timeout, source_address=source_address)
   ...:
   ...: urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = set_src_addr
   ...:
   ...: import requests
   ...: r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org')
```

It fails with the following exception:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10c4b89b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address",))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will document the solution I have found and list some problems I had in the process.

[salparadise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62138/salparadise) had it right. It is very similar to the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip/12590625#12590625) I have found. I am assuming that the `requests` module import the `urllib3` and the latter has its own version of the `socket` library. Therefore, it is very likely that the `requests` module will never directly call the `socket` library, but will have its functionality provided by the `urllib3` module.

I have not noticed it first, but the third snippet I had in my question was working. The problem why I had a `ConnectionError` is because I was trying to use a [macvlan](http://hicu.be/macvlan-vs-ipvlan) virtual interface over a wireless physical interface (which, if I understood correctly, drops packets if the MAC addresses do not match). Therefore, the following solution does work:

```
import requests                                
from socket import socket as backup            
import socket                                  
def socket_custom_src_ip(src_ip):              
    original_socket = backup                   
    def bound_socket(*args, **kwargs):         
        sock = original_socket(*args, **kwargs)
        sock.bind((src_ip, 0))                 
        print(sock)                            
        return sock                            
    return bound_socket
```

In my problem, I will need to change the IP address of a socket several times. One of the problems I had was that if no backup of the socket function is made, changing it several times would cause an error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. This occurs since on the second change, the `socket.socket` function would not be the original one. Therefore, my solution above creates a copy of the original socket function to use as a backup for further bindings of different IPs.

Lastly, following is a proof of concept of how to achieve multiple processes using different libraries. With this idea, I can import and monkey-patch each socket inside my processes, having different monkey-patched versions of them.

```
import importlib                                     
import multiprocessing                               
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):            
    def __init__(self, module):                      
        super().__init__()                           
        self.module = module                         
    def run(self):                                   
        i = importlib.import_module(f'{self.module}')
        print(f'{i}')
p1 = MyProcess('os')                                                          
p2 = MyProcess('sys')                
p1.start()                                                                    
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py'>
p2.start()                           
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

This also works using the `import` statement and `global` keyword to provide transparent access inside all functions as the following

```
import multiprocessing                   
def fun(self):                           
    import os                            
    global os                            
    os.var = f'{repr(self)}'             
    fun2()                               
def fun2():                              
    print(os.system(f'echo "{os.var}"')) 
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):                  
        super().__init__()               
    def run(self):                       
        if 'os' in dir():                
            print('os already imported') 
        fun(self)                                            
p1 = MyProcess()                                                              
p2 = MyProcess()                                                              
p2.start()                                                                  
<MyProcess(MyProcess-2, started)>                                 
p1.start()                                        
<MyProcess(MyProcess-1, started)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where I wanted to have some localhost traffic originating not from 127.0.0.1 ( I was testing a https connection over localhost)

This is how I did it using the python core libraries `ssl` and `http.client` (cf [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.client.html)), as it seemed cleaner than the solutions I found online using the `requests` library.

```
    import http.client as http
    import ssl

    dst= 'sever.infsec.local' # dns record was added to OS
    src = ('127.0.0.2',0) # 0 -> select available port 

    context = ssl.SSLContext()
    context.load_default_certs() # loads OS certifcate context

    request = http.HTTPSConnection(dst, 443, context=context,
                                   source_address=src)

    request.connect()

    request.request("GET", '/', json.dumps(request_data))
    response = request.getresponse()
```