# Can a single machine make requests from multiple different IP Addresses?

Tags: networking, python-requests, ip-address, proxies

I am a complete rookie when it comes to networking and my question is theoretical. Let's say I have 3 public IP Addresses, and want to request a webpage X every few minutes. If webpage X places a cap of 10 requests per day on the requesting IP, is it at all possible to make requests via Python from the same machine but different IP Addresses?

Example:

```
+--------+    +----( Request 1 from IP: 1.2.3.4 )------+    +--------+
| Client |----+----( Request 2 from IP: 5.6.7.8 )------+----| Server |
+--------+    +----( Request 3 from IP: 9.10.11.12 )---+    +--------+
```

I have tried to research things, but my knowledge is so small in this area, that I don't quite know what my question is... Is this something where a proxy would be useful?

Comment: does [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996494/send-http-request-through-specific-network-interface) help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is to create a list of proxy servers and send every `K` (10 in your example) requests via a different proxy server. So if your list include `N` proxy servers you can send `N*K` requests per day.

You can setup your own servers or use different proxy server providers, Some of them are free.

See: [how to use proxy with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)